# Can I send a build to TestFlight without AppStore validation?

Tags: ios, testing, app-store-connect, testflight

I'm currently sending builds with the iTunes Connect, but it always run a AppStore validation of the application. 
I feel like I'm doing something wrong because the app is raw and it's meant only for testers yet and I don't want the apple team (or, hopefully, robots) to process it every time for me.

Is it the "iTunes Connect -> TestFlight" chain a primary way to distribute the builds for testers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the app to be distributed to your testers - even **Internal** testers - it has to be installed on the device via TestFlight.

During the process of uploading to iTC, the app must pass at a minimum the necessary structure to *enable* it to be installed and run.

The "Apple Team" doesn't look at it unless you submit it for **External** testers, but the automated process will make sure you're uploading an actual app, not submitting a plain textfile (yeah, silly example, but you get the idea).

Answer (score 0):

Yes TestFlight **is the recommended way** by Apple to distribute your beta application to testers.

However, there are alternative ways to send your application to beta reviewers, such as [Fabric](http://fabric.io) and [HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net).